# What makes the SCR burnt up?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I removed Pin 1 to trace nuisance tripping of this GFCI circuit, and the SCR blows up:

[image: 1]

From this circuit:

[image: 2]

Removing pin 1 will make the pin 7 trigger the SCR continuously. But why would the SCR blow up?  Are there AC SCR that can only be turned on or pathway between anode and cathode only on momentarily and not continuously?

Comment: don't remove pin1 then!

Comment: if I remove pin 2 and 3. the SCR won't burn anymore. I just want to understand if there are many kinds of SCR. It's not identified what kind of SCR is used in the GFCI outlet circuit.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the GFCI can trip from inductive kick from motor by causing capacitive coupling within the circuit that can falsely trip it. I'm tracing what parts do it exactly.

Comment: start by isolating the motor, or the supply.  from ground, if that solves the problem it's the motor leaking

Comment: done all that.. is inductive kick from motor able to induce capacitor coupling inside GFCI circuit that can trip the SCR not an accepted scenario? why?

Answer (score 2):

The relay is a "latching contacts" relay, which means that it will mechanically latch in that position until it is otherwise reset.

That means that it only requires a relatively short pulse out of the SCR, which it will get as the opening of the relay will cause the fault condition to be removed and thus the SCR to be turned off. That means that they just have to specify the SCR to conduct for a few hundred milliseconds at a time, thus limiting its power dissipation and current requirements.

If they designed it this way, which is very likely for a consumer market device, by turning on the SCR continuously you are probably exceeding its safe operating region.

Comment: what kind of SCR can conduct AC continuously?

Comment: @Jtl the kind that is being driven continuously through its gate.